# Returning index of the list while updating the count of Comparator comparing function

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, comparator, indexof

I am sorting one list by using a another list. Sorting intention is to, bring the elements which are present in array B to the top of array A if array contains those elements.

eg:

`inputA = {"A", "B", "G"}
 inputB = {"G", "F"}
 output should be A = {"G", "A", "B"}`

My sorting code looks like below

```
Collections.sort( inputA, 
           Comparator.comparing( a -> inputB.indexOf( a ) > -1 ? -1 : a.getIndex()));
```

My real code is not this but the idea is same. Real code contains two generic lists wth complex objects.

My sorting code works properly. What I want to do is while I am returning `-1` or `a.getIndex()`, I want to get the count of the no.of `-1`'s returned.

How can I do this inside this code? Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

`inputA = {"A", "B", "C", "G"}
 inputB = {"G", "B"}
 output should be A = {"B", "G", "A", "C"}`

The output I am getting is 
`output = {"B", "G", "C", "A"}`

In the original `inputA` element "C" follows after element "A". But in my result I am getting it in the reverse order.

How can I fix this?

`a.getIndex()` returns an integer which contains the original order. It seems like the comparator is not using it to sort it.

Comment: what about if inputB contains `{"A","G", "F"}`?

Comment: *I want to get the count of the no.of -1's returned*... where do you want to use it? and is it the number of elements in `inputA` not present in `inputB`, that you're interested in?

Answer (score 2):

This `a.getIndex()` expression is leading into a wrong direction. The sort operation is guaranteed to be stable, which means, elements being equal according to the comparator will not change their relative order.

So if you have

```
List<String> inputA = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "G");
List<String> inputB = Arrays.asList("G", "F");
```

and use

```
inputA.sort(Comparator.comparing(inputB::contains).reversed());
```

you will get the order `[G, A, B]`.

Likewise,

```
List<String> inputA = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "G");
List<String> inputB = Arrays.asList("G", "B");

inputA.sort(Comparator.comparing(inputB::contains).reversed());
```

will lead to `[B, G, A, C]`. Since the provided comparator’s only criteria is whether the element is contained in the other list, the relative order of the elements within each of the two groups (“contained” and “not contained”) will not change.

Note that if `listB` is rather large, the repeated linear search may cause performance problems. This can be solved by using a temporary hash set for fast lookup:

```
inputA.sort(Comparator.comparing(new HashSet<>(inputB)::contains).reversed());
```

Comment: *The sort operation is guaranteed to be stable...* isn't that true for a *certain* sorting algorithm though, not in general?

Comment: @Eugene the documentation of [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) says “This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*” while at the same time, it says that it will delegate to `List.sort`. Unfortunately, the documentation of `List.sort` does not make it that clear that overriding methods must retains the *stable* property. In practice, there are no collections overriding them with a different algorithm. Some eliminate the copying overhead or introduce synchronization, but still use the same algorithm.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly where my confusion was coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a counter which gets incremented every time a `-1` is returned. Here's your modified code:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
Collections.sort(a, Comparator.comparing(s -> {
    if (b.indexOf(s) > -1) {
        count.incrementAndGet();
        return -1;
    }
    return a.indexOf(s);
}));
System.out.println(count.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the count of `-1`s is equivalent to the size of the intersection of `inputA` and `inputB`. You can use the following snippet to get this value:

```
var distinctB = Set.copyOf(inputB);
long commonSize = inputA.stream().filter(distinctB::contains).count();
```

This assumes that `inputA` and `inputB` are some `Collection` (you stated *generic lists*).

Comment: I don't get it - the OP does not care about shred size, at all

Comment: @Eugene OP wants to get the count of `-1`s returned by his `Comparator`, and `-1`s only occur when `inputB.indexOf(a) > -1` is `true`, hence the intersection

Comment: @JacobG. true that's what I could infer based on the question text as well, but which is a strange requirement though.. and returning `-1` when the element is found is further puzzling me... and it ideally seems like `long count = inputA.stream().filter(inputB::contains).count();` is what they are looking for.

Comment: @nullpointer *returning `-1` when element is found* is fine because the element needs to be pushed to the front, so we need a negative number to denote that this element is "smaller"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
Vector<String> inputA = new Vector();
Vector<String> inputB = new Vector();
// fill elements/ get userelements 
// ...

//push to front:
for(String element:inputB){
    if(inputA.remove(element)){
        inputA.add(0, element);
    }
}
```

Some linked list as container should be more performant. Arrays will have a lot of copyoverhad - not the best choice. But choice of the container is up to you...